# Finding determinant of a 5x5 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Can I get some help in computing the determinant of this 5x5 matrix? I am confused with regards to the triangular form and how I go about deriving the determinant from that form in terms of a, b and c.

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
  1&2&0&0&0\\
  0&1&2&a&0\\
  0&0&3&-1&0\\
  0&0&0&b&1\\
  5&0&0&0&c
\end{array}
\right] $$

Comment: Expand in terms of "minors" is quite quick because there are so many zeros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, Laplace expansion along the highlighted rows/columns:
$$\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix}
  \color{red}{1}&\color{red}{2}&\color{red}{0}&\color{red}{0}&\color{red}{0}\\
  0&1&2&a&0\\
  0&0&3&-1&0\\
  0&0&0&b&1\\
  5&0&0&0&c
\end{vmatrix} &= \\
=1\cdot (-1)^{1+1}\cdot 3bc+2\cdot (-1)^{1+2} \begin{vmatrix}
\color{red}{0}&2&a&0\\ 
\color{red}{0}&3&-1&0\\ 
\color{red}{0}&0&b&1\\ 
\color{red}{5}&0&0&c
\end{vmatrix}&=\\
=3bc-2\cdot 5\cdot (-1)^{4+1}
\begin{vmatrix}
2&a&\color{red}{0}\\ 
3&-1&\color{red}{0}\\ 
0&b&\color{red}{1}
\end{vmatrix}&=\\
=3bc+10\cdot 1\cdot (-1)^{3+3}
\begin{vmatrix}2&a\\ 3&-1\end{vmatrix}&=\\
=3bc +10(-2-3a)&=\\
=3bc-20-30a&.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Do the following steps where in, $R$ is a row of the matrix. At the end, we will have a upper triangle matrix:

1. $-5R_1+R_5\to R_5~~$
2. $10R_2+R_5\to R_5~~$
3. $-\frac{20}{3}R_3+R_5\to R_5~~$
4. $\frac{-10a+20/3}{b}R_4+R_5\to R_5$.

This way is not unique!